# Hiding button if all status is "Paid" using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project where I want to display and hide a button when all Status is "Paid".

The Status sometimes will be list of Status and sometimes will be single Status.
I need a code using LINQ to check if the all Status are "Paid",hide this button.
 here is the code and what i'm trying to do...

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PaymentList)
{
//Here i want to check if all item.Status=="Paid"  
if(item.Status=="Paid")
{
//if true i want to display my button
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
}
else
{
<button type="button" >Click Me!</button>
else hide my button
}                            
}
```

i want to know if i can do this using LINQ,Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything ? can you show some code ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show some code so we know what you are talking about and how to help you. What is this "Status" and where do you check it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [You've been a member here for 4 months](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6124780/mhmd) and it seems that [you showed some code in your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6124780/mhmd?tab=questions&sort=newest), so please do the same for this question.

Comment: @gypsyCoder i updated the question please check it and help me

Comment: ,@René Vogt i updated the question please check it and help me

Comment: @,ekad i updated the question please check it and help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
@if(!Model.PaymentList.All(f=>f.Status=="Paid"))
{
    <button>click me</button>
}
```

Or the `Any` method

```
@if(Model.PaymentList.All(f=>f.Status!="Paid"))
{
    <button>click me</button>
}
```

Comment: thank you so so so much, this what i was looking for,your code is working great.